# Remove objects with duplicate date property from Array

Tags: arrays, swift, duplicates

I have this array of objects. Each object has, among other, a "startPoint" property, which is a Date.

Now, I want to make sure that there are no objects with the same "startPoint", regardless of the values of other properties.

So, I found a potential approach, that works for Strings, but not for Dates:

```
var uniqueValues = Set<String>()
result = result.filter{ uniqueValues.insert("\($0.startPoint)").inserted}
```

Could anyone of you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your object could implement Equatable (by comparing the startPoint properties). Then you can use Set in the same way as with strings.

Comment: Can you check if an object with that `startPoint` already exists in the array before appending the new element? Instead of having to go through a Set, and then mutate `result`

Comment: @carpsen: this array is well-filled

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work for Dates, what do you mean? What happens?

Comment: @Ashley Mills: My array still contains objects with the same date as property

Comment: So you have values in your final array with _exactly_ the same Date value?

Comment: @Ashley Mills: you might be onto something here. While the date is the same, the time might differ.

Comment: @Sjakelien Yep - that's what I was getting at. Use the Y,M,D date components to unique on

Comment: "While the date is the same, the time might differ". Two `Date` objects with different times are not the same `Date`. A Date must match another date down to the smallest fraction of a millisecond in order to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use date components to unique on, so you ignore the time part

```
struct Record {
    let date: Date
    let name: String
}

let now = Date()
let soon = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 100) 
let future = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: now)!
let records = [Record(date: now, name: "Now"), 
               Record(date: soon, name: "Soon"),  // same day so should be removed
               Record(date: future, name: "Future")]


var unique = Set<DateComponents>()
let result = records.filter {
    let comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: $0.date)
    if unique.contains(comps) {
        return false
    }
    unique.insert(comps)
    return true
}
print(result)

// [Record(date: 2018-10-11 13:47:17 +0000, name: "Now"),
//  Record(date: 2018-10-12 13:47:17 +0000, name: "Future")]
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer. The `Calendar` class has a method `isDate(_:inSameDayAs:)` but I don't see a way to remove duplicates in a performant way using that function.

Answer (score -1):

My approach is similar to the other answer, but is slightly more performant since it uses a `Dictionary` instead of an `Array`. There is a cost, though: You lose ordering like you would with the `Set` approach.

```
struct MyObject {
  let startPoint: Date
}

let values: [MyObject] = [...]

let unique = Array(
  values.reduce(into: [Date: MyObject]()) { result, value in
    result[value.startPoint] = result[value.startPoint] ?? value
  }.values
)
```